# Is lg*(n) time complexity better than lg(n)?

Tags: time-complexity, logarithm

I am trying to understand the time complexity of the lg*(n) [log*(n) base 2] in comparison to lg(n) and I wonder which of them is faster...can someone explain it, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, the iterative logarithm (log*) is one of the slowest growing time complexities. In fact, of all the commonly uses complexities, it is the second slowest, beaten only by the inverse Ackerman function. This means it grows significantly slower, and as a result completes much faster, than the log function.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm#Analysis_of_algorithms

Comment: Thank you :) it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen `lg*(n)` notation before, but I assume you're referring to log base 2 vs log base 10.  It turns out that `log2(N) == log10(N) * 3.32192809489...`, which is a constant factor difference, and we drop constant factors when analyzing algorithmic complexity. As a result, all logarithms are considered equal, and we do not need to bother specifying the base in algorithmic complexity.

When studying actual runtimes, then log10(N) is faster than log2(N), but very rarely do developers actually analyze runtimes in this manner, they usually do it with a profiler.

Comment: actually lg*(n) is the iterative logarithm which gets the log of each result until it reaches 1.

Comment: And lg*(n) is as same as log*(n) base 2 (lg is used for base 2 logarithms).